# Проблема с кликом JS

Tags: javascript

Не пойму почему не работает клик. Делаю клик по элементу с `id` `link_2`, но он не срабатывает.

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.querySelector.contains(`link_${2}`)) {
        console.log('сработало');
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

И не будет срабатывать. `e.target` - это тот элемент, который кликнули. Скорее всего, `.querySelector.contains(...)` надо заменить на `.closest("#link2")`.

Comment: Использовать `closest` с делегированием на весь `document` весьма рискованно, особенно если элементов с данным `id` больше чем один.

Comment: @NikitaSmith, ты какую-то ерунду говоришь... Во-первых, какая разница куда делегирование, если closest ищет не в документе, а от `event.target`? Во-вторых, а какого перепуга id должны быть одинаковые?

Comment: Да самый простой пример, если ты будешь загружать какие-нибудь новости на страницу через тот же `handlbars`  из массива объектов,  то делегирование надо вешать на шаблонную форму. И `closest` никогда не дает гарантии того, что ты нажал именно на нужный элемент. Спорить не собираюсь.

Comment: @NikitaSmith, _"И closest никогда не дает гарантии того, что ты нажал именно на нужный элемент"_ - что значит не даёт? Вообще не понимаю, что тебя с ним не устраивает.

Answer (score 0):

Какой-то весьма извращенный способ узнать id элемента

> `e.target.querySelector.contains`

Я даже не буду спрашивать, что вы хотели этим сделать

```js
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'link_2') {
    console.log('сработало');
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="link_1">Link 1</div>
<div id="link_2">Link 2</div>
```

Comment: Если есть вложенные элементы, то будет так себе работать...

Comment: @Qwertiy Угу. Но автор пишет `Делаю клик по элементу с id link_2`. Отсюда делаем вывод, что вложенности нет

Comment: Но `querySelector.contains` напоминает поиск...

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/842694/178988 - я угадал)

Comment: @Qwertiy Ну и кто автору виноват, что он не умеет формулировать свои мысли?