# Не срабатывает клик на вложенные элементы

Tags: javascript, html

Сделал разметку, требуется чтобы по клику на любой из трех тегов `a` срабатывал клик.

```
<div class="games_list_tabs">
    <a id="link_${item_div_num}" class="games_list_tab">
        <span class="games_list_tab_icon">
        <img src="https://"></span>
        <span class="games_list_tab_name">Game1</span>
        <span class="games_list_tab_number">79</span>
    </a>
    <div class="games_list_tab_separator"></div>
    <a id="link_${item_div_num}" class="games_list_tab">
        <span class="games_list_tab_icon">
        <img src="https://"></span>
        <span class="games_list_tab_name">Game2</span>
        <span class="games_list_tab_number">54</span>
    </a>
    <div class="games_list_tab_separator"></div>
    <a id="link_${item_div_num}" class="games_list_tab">
        <span class="games_list_tab_icon">
        <img src="https://"></span>
        <span class="games_list_tab_name">Game3</span>
        <span class="games_list_tab_number">29</span>
    </a>
    <div class="games_list_tab_separator"></div>
</div>
```

Делаю сам клик, но он работает только на тег `a`, а на те что внутри не срабатывает. Почему так происходит?

```
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.id == 'link_${item_div_num}') {
    console.log('сработало');
  }
});
```

Comment: Ну я ж вчера говорил: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/842595/178988

Answer (score 2):

```
    document.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
       if (e.target.closest('.games_list_tab').id == 'link_${item_div_num}') {
          console.log('сработало');
        }
     });
```

Target - это нода на которой сработало событие..это может быть и картинка и ссылка..и id у них нет, поэтому и не сработало. 
И еще..замечание..несколько элементов с одинаковыми id быть не должно.потому что поиск по id  в DOM всегда будет  возвращать только первый элемент.

Answer (score 1):

Не у всех ваших элементов есть `id`, ваш пример кода работает только на `id=link_${item_div_num}`.

Атрибут `id` должен быть уникален на странице, если нужно многократное использование атрибута, воспользуйтесь `class`.

```js
var aa = document.querySelectorAll('a');
// 
aa.forEach(function(a) {
  // Проходим по всем элементам <a> вешаем событие
  a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Выводим то что вызвало событие
    console.log('Clicked: Tag[' + e.target.tagName + '], Class[' 
                                + e.target.classList + '], ID['
                                + e.target.id + ']');
  })
})
```

```css
a {
  background: #D46A6A;
  padding: 2px;
}

span {
  padding: 3px;
}

.games_list_tab_icon {
  background: yellow;
}

.games_list_tab_name {
  background: #ccc;
}

.games_list_tab_number {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="games_list_tabs">
  <a id="link_${item_div_num}" class="games_list_tab">
    <span class="games_list_tab_icon">
        <img src="//picsum.photos/200/300"></span>
    <span class="games_list_tab_name">Game1</span>
    <span class="games_list_tab_number">79</span>
        Линк
  </a>
  <div class="games_list_tab_separator"></div>
  <a id="link_${item_div_num}" class="games_list_tab">
    <span class="games_list_tab_icon">
        <img src="//picsum.photos/200/301"></span>
    <span class="games_list_tab_name">Game2</span>
    <span class="games_list_tab_number">54</span>
  </a>
  <div class="games_list_tab_separator"></div>
  <a id="link_${item_div_num}" class="games_list_tab">
    <span class="games_list_tab_icon">
        <img src="//picsum.photos/200/302"></span>
    <span class="games_list_tab_name">Game3</span>
    <span class="games_list_tab_number">29</span>
  </a>
  <div class="games_list_tab_separator"></div>
</div>
```

---

[Про события](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

[Про элемент А](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a)